# How to set the anchoredPosition of a RectTransform via script in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to set the anchoredPosition of a UI image instance programmatically.
I have tried these ways:

```
GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition=new Vector2(0,0);
```

and

```
GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition.Set(0,0);
```

But none of the above seem to work. Infact when I run the program, in the inspector it always says the anchoredPosition is (0.5,0.5). And it always puts the image where it likes. What is that?

Comment: Shouldn't you just change the pivot point?

Comment: the pivot is a different thing

Comment: Where are you calling this from, because the first one you gave should work.  Are you sure that line of code is being called? Also it this item in under a Layout Group? because if so that will overwrite anything that you do in code

Comment: I drop the image on another image that has a GridLayoutGroup attached. Maybe that's why.